# How to use nested loop over few lists in R?

Tags: r

I want to use loop a chunk of code over the “Split_T_series” splitted lists in R. I have used the following code to split,

`Split_T_series = split(Samp_Carb_Cal, Samp_Carb_Cal$...2)`

basically its splitting the "Samp_Carb_Cal" into 3 lists. Now for each of the lists, i want to repeat a chunnk of code that consists few "for loop" in it.

I have tried this,

```
Output_<- c()
for (i in 1:3){

Output_[i] <-as.numeric(Split_T_series[i]$`i`$`t soil / Ha...7`)

t_sl_<- c()
for (i in 1:3){
t_sl_[i]<-Split_T_series[i]$`i`$cm...9
t_sl_
}
t_sl_

BD_sl_<- c()
for (i in 1:3){
  BD_sl_[i]<-Split_T_series[i]$`i`$`g / cm3`
  BD_sl_
}
BD_sl_

A_coring<-round(PA_n_Sampling[52,4],2) 

Gravel_percent<-20

gGi_<- c()
for (i in 1:3){
  gGi_[i]<- as.numeric(BD_sl_[i]*A_coring*t_sl_[i]*Gravel_percent/100)
  gGi_
}
gGi_<-(gGi_)
Output_[i][,7]<-gGi_
head(Output_[i])
}
```

As a final output, I want to have three separate output lists (Output_1,Output_2 and Output_3).  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and edit your original question rather than asking a new question without any change.